# Spell Checking in Publishing pages

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

QST1: Anyone know how to turn off the spell checking when clicking publish on a publishing page? Tried disabling farm feature without effect.

QST2: Do you need the language pack installed for Norwegian spell check?

QST3: Can one change the dictionary language using client code, for example by combobox in the publishing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QST1: You can simulate this by setting language as in qst3 to a LCID which doesn't exist or is not installed. You will then get a message in dialogs saying the language is not installed. In most cases better than showing x spellcheck errors. This is for the automatic spell check that happens on checkin/publish, the spellcheck icon can be hidden by the usual Ribbon removal procedure,

QST2: Yes

QST3: Yes by doing something similar to this:

```
function changeSpellCheckLanguage(languageSelected) {
    if (languageSelected == "Norwegian") {
        SP.UI.Spellcheck.SpellChecker.currentLanguage = 1044;
    } 
}
```

to change initial default this js can be run after "spell" variable has been loaded.

```
function setDefaultSpellCheckLanguage(languageSelected) {
    if (languageSelected == "Norwegian") {
        spellcheck.defaultLanguage = 1044;
}
```

Comment: QST3. For release version(where debug=false in web.config) you must instead use SP.UI.Spellcheck.SpellChecker.$5 instead of CurrentLanguage. This is because the release JS in Sharepoint is optimized and variable names are compressed. You can for example check for HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled in codebehind and write out the required script.

Answer (score 1):

We have same issue with spell check in publishihng site... created MSDN support case and that was just a nightmare... After a long time trying to explain and show the issue, they came back with a workaround, which was to delete the content of the SP.UI.Spellcheck.js. This greyed out the spelling button in the Ribbon... I tried to explain how wrong this suggestion is, along with the fact that it does not fix the actual issue.

Hopefully this bug will get cleared up in a release.